# What happens when DynamoDBMapper.save() fails?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I wonder if the `DynamoDBMapper.save()` is asynchronous and what happens when something goes wrong? Should I surround the save with `try` / `catch` to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When using the `save`, `load`, and `delete` methods, [`DynamoDBMapper`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html) will throw [`DynamoDBMappingException`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMappingException.html)s to indicate that domain classes are incorrectly annotated or otherwise incompatible with this class. Service exceptions will always be propagated as [`SdkClientException`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/SdkClientException.html), and DynamoDB-specific subclasses such as [`ConditionalCheckFailedException`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/ConditionalCheckFailedException.html) will be used when possible.

<sup>[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html)</sup>

So, if anything goes wrong, you'll get an exception. But all those exceptions are inherited from `RuntimeException`, i.e. you are not required to catch them. But you are not banned of doing that: you can wrap your code in a try-catch and process them as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know if the save is asynchronous? I need to be sure that the statement after the save will not be executed before saving the item

Comment: It is synchronous. If it was asynchronous, it would return some kind of a future or deferred result, so that you could keep track of the operation status.